# Force quit play framework application

Tags: jboss, playframework, playframework-2.0, port

I am unable to bind to my regular port 9000 with the typical error message:

```
[error] org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelException: Failed to bind to: /0.0.0.0:9000
```

However, I do not have anything currently running on that port..

Checking what port 9000 is listing to:

```
sudo lsof -i -P | grep "9000"
```

gives me:

```
java       2642      ow  137u  IPv6 0xe9a3870d7acf02fd      0t0    TCP *:9000 (LISTEN)
java       2642      ow  142u  IPv6 0xe9a3870d7e430f1d      0t0    TCP localhost:9000->localhost:62403 (CLOSE_WAIT)
java       2642      ow  156u  IPv6 0xe9a3870d856676dd      0t0    TCP localhost:9000->localhost:60860 (CLOSE_WAIT)
```

Any idea how to close this?

---

**Edit**

Turns out google chrome is using my 9000 which is kind of weird

```
Google    51558      ow  125u  IPv4 0xe9a3870d8683581d      0t0    TCP localhost:61238->localhost:9000 (ESTABLISHED)
```

When I killed it, chrome crashed

Guess I'll have to start using a different port!

Answer (score 7):

Play isn't running anymore?

Otherwise for reference, one can find the Play process with `ps auxwww | grep play` and kill it with`kill <pid>` or `kill -9 <pid>`.

Comment: Hmm.. this killed the process, but I still can't bind to 9000 with the same jboss error message... weird

Comment: When in doubt, use brute force - try `killall java`.

Comment: this helped on mac osx, FWIW.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue with play framework using scalaVersion := "2.11.7".

```
java      19068  ecamur  342u  IPv6 40371923      0t0  TCP *:9000 (LISTEN)
```

I killed  using bellow comment

```
kill -9 19068
```

It appeared to be nothing was crashed. I ran the application without any issue.

Answer (score 0):

I've often the same problem when my Play application hang out without releasing the socket.

The easiest solution I found is to restart the network interface.

```
ifconfig en0 down
ifconfig en0 up
```

(Assuming `en0` is your main interface)